# WCF Application hosted service not appearing in Service Manager

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, console-application

Simple question really.

I have an application hosted WCF Service running on my server.  This Service is in it's early stages of development.  I want it to be "self healing".

When I run the service (by double clicking the .exe to run the console application which creates it) I'm not seeing the service appears under Services in either Task Manager or the typical Windows Service Manager.

Am I missing something?

What's the best approach to make this self-healing (restart on crash).

Thanks

Comment: It is not appearing because you are running an application that hosts a service, it is not running as a windows service. Change your console app into a service and install using sc.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a project type of Windows Service In Visual Studio and install the built exe file as a windows service in order to see it in Service panel.

Windows services have to be built as such from the start. You cannot take just any executable and install it as a windows service.

More information on MSDN: [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).